# Set React swipeable area

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, hyperlink

I am doing a project in react. I used the react-swipeable library to my project to page transition now the problem is it disables all the hyperlinks in the selected div. To get rid of this problem I just want a swipeable area just like the following image. [A demo mobile pic][1], which means the swipeable area should be in the yellow portion. I am not specifying the quantity of the portion, just want to get the idea.

I have tried with the code

```
const swipeWrapper: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 200
  }
<div style={swipeWrapper}>

#code of pages

</div>
```

I can not make the swipeWrapper style like the image. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkLgx.png